# QGIS: Merge polygons leaves line segments behind

Tags: merge, polygon, qgis

I am trying to merge several polygons together based upon an attribute... I have tried by QGIS' dissolve and merge functions. Both leave behind stray polylines once theyve completed (see pre and post example screenshots below). Im assuming this is a result of the shapefile and a tolerance for line geometry?

Has anyone else had this problem and found something that works?

thanks

mike

[pre-merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMctM.jpg)

[post-merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN66h.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Best option I have found from looking around for same issue is.

Convert layer to Line (Vector>Geometry Tools>Polygons to Lines)
and then convert the new layer "Lines from Polygons" back to Polygons (Vector>Geometry Tools>Lines to Polygons)

Now run v.clean for "Polygons from lines" and choose the cleaning tool "rmarea" and set the Threshold to something that works depending on smallest polygon, I used "0.5"

This cleans out the unwanted line bits - they layer cleaned should be what you are after, but you may end up with all your polygons split into there own feature - (one row for every polygon in attribute table)

Try creating a ID type column to easily sort them back

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C17kW.png),[Polygons to Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXcNb.png), [Lines to Polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtoEj.png), [Cleaned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfQxK.png),
 [Removed - Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTuw0.png)

Answer (score -1):

I snapped the vertices and still had a line segment, so I created a new feature that laid over the offending line and made sure two of the new feature's vertices were snapped to the line's two endpoints. Then I merged this new feature to the one with the ghost line segment, and the ghost segment went away.